# GNU Make removes downloaded zip files for no apparent reason

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, archive

I have this makefile tha sthould download and build openssh (along with other things):

```
ROOT_DIR=$(PWD)
DATA_DIR=$(ROOT_DIR)/data
SOURCES_DIR=$(ROOT_DIR)/sources
RESOURCES_DIR=$(ROOT_DIR)/resources
DRAFTS_DIR=$(ROOT_DIR)/drafts

$(SOURCES_DIR):
    mkdir $(SOURCES_DIR)

$(RESOURCES_DIR):
    mkdir $(RESOURCES_DIR)

$(DRAFTS_DIR):
    mkdir $(DRAFTS_DIR)

openssh-tar-url="ftp://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-6.2p2.tar.gz"
TAR_PROJECTS += openssh
openssh:
    echo "Building $@"

openssh-clean: openssh-archive-clean

.SECONDEXPANSION :
$(TAR_PROJECTS) :  $(SOURCES_DIR) $(SOURCES_DIR)/$$@-archive

$(DRAFTS_DIR)/%.tar.gz: $(DRAFTS_DIR)
    echo "Pulling $*."
    wget $($*-tar-url) -O $(DRAFTS_DIR)/$*.tar.gz

.SECONDEXPANSION :
$(SOURCES_DIR)/%-archive : | $(DRAFTS_DIR)/$$*.tar.gz
    mkdir $@
    cd $@ && tar xvzf $(DRAFTS_DIR)/$*.tar.gz

%-archive-clean:
    rm -rf $(SOURCES_DIR)/$*-archive $(DRAFTS_DIR)/$*.tar.gz
```

When i run `make openssh` it runs correctly but at the end it removes the archive it downloaded. This is very strange to me:

```
$ make openssh --just-print
echo "Pulling openssh."
wget "ftp://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-6.2p2.tar.gz" -O /home/fakedrake/Projects/ThinkSilicon/xilinx-zynq-bootstrap/drafts/openssh.tar.gz
mkdir /home/fakedrake/Projects/ThinkSilicon/xilinx-zynq-bootstrap/sources/openssh-archive
cd /home/fakedrake/Projects/ThinkSilicon/xilinx-zynq-bootstrap/sources/openssh-archive && tar xvzf /home/fakedrake/Projects/ThinkSilicon/xilinx-zynq-bootstrap/drafts/openssh.tar.gz
echo "Building openssh"
rm /home/fakedrake/Projects/ThinkSilicon/xilinx-zynq-bootstrap/drafts/openssh.tar.gz
```

Comment: Use `make -d` to see which rule is triggering the `rm` and why...

Comment: Aha thank you `Removing intermediate files...`. Can you tell me how to stop it from doing that for this specific intermediate (in an answer so i can accept it) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you can list targets (and intermediates) as `.PRECIOUS` to avoid them being deleted for you. I'm afraid you'll need to RTFM for more details - I'm in visual studio rather than make these days, so my make skills are a bit rusty...

Comment: That worked not sure which one is more 'correct', reading the **** manual I came across `.SECONDARY` which is strictly speaking a bit closer to what I asked for. If I used a download tool that could interrupt and continue download of the archinve I think `.PRECIOUS` would be much better. But we are splitting hairs here, they both work thank you!